# Using Markdown as a Grails View

Tags: grails, markdown

We're writing a grails (Grails 2.1.1) project where, for some of our views, we want to use markdown instead of gsp files.

At the moment we can do this using the [markdown plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/markdown) in a special layout. This allows us to render markdown views like so:

`render(layout: 'docs', view: 'markdown')`

However, this requires the markdown page to have a .gsp extension, when, for practical reasons, we need it to have a .md extension.

Does anyone know a better way to use markdown as a grails view? It would be great if we can avoid using the .gsp extension.

Comment: I think there's some way to map other files as gsp files, for example look at GSP-arse plugin, it maps .js files as gsp so that js files will be processed just like its a gsp file. It might be the solution.

Comment: Thanks. Gonna look to see how they implement that and see if it's something we can use. Will report back!

Comment: check this project: https://github.com/edvinasbartkus/grails-mustache

Comment: Thanks! Moustache isn't exactly what we're looking for, though :(

Comment: What we've landed up doing is keeping the markdown in the conf directory, so that we can get to it using the *getResource* set of methods. We then read in the text and pass it to a dedicated view gsp. It's not ideal, but it was simple to get working for this small project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Short Answer

You're not going to be able to without some heavy modifications. The distributed GrailsViewResolver is hard-tied to .gsp and .jsp extensions.

See [grails-core on github](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-web/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/view/GrailsViewResolver.java#L54) for verification.

## The Long Answer

You might be able to fashion your own Ant task to hook it into the Compile cycle of your Grails application so that, at a minimum, you can compile your *.md files through the GroovyPageCompiler.

That process might look something like [this](https://gist.github.com/3927274) (though not exactly, since I am relying on the plugin's taglib to do the rendering in this case, for simplicity).

But this doesn't solve all of your problems. You would also need to register a new view resolver, and to do that you would inevitably go down the road of rewriting the [GrailsDispatcherServlet](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-web/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/GrailsDispatcherServlet.java).

It sounds like your solution of storing the files in the conf directory might be your best (although dirty) bet for now. Maybe somebody will take the time to allow for configurable GSP file extensions in the future, and that might solve your problem down the road.

I hope you find some of this information useful.

Comment: Oh thanks, I'll have a look at those classes during the week. I wonder how easy it will be to use Spring to swap them out with specialised subclasses. Although I'm mostly happy with our current solution, I think this might be much of the answer to the question (will decide shortly).

Comment: Yeah, that's doable, but you'll have to subclass every part of the application framework that statically defines the .gsp extension. This can quickly get out of hand and become unmaintainable. A better solution would be to add a task to the compile phase that copies your .md files to a .gsp extension prior to the gsp's being compiled (maybe eventCompileStart hook), then afterwards clean up the .gsp's in the project directories. That's what I've done in the past for a similar goal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that if we decide to use this documentation technique for a larger project, we will probably look into making a plugin to rename the .md files, or something similar. For the time being, I think we're happy with the conf directory method!

Answer (score 0):

I did pretty much the same thing but with another approach today. I wanted to serve the readme file of the project so I couldn't really move it anywhere. I ended up soft linking it from `readme.md` to `grails-app/views/readme/readme.gsp`. I [posted](http://highlevelbits.com/2014/11/markdown-readme-from-grails.html) about the whole thing.

And yes - soft linking works if you and all your coworkers are on *-nix - so it is not a platformsafe way to do it.